# How can I access NavigationParameters from the xViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

From the first view I navigate to a second xView with the following code:

```
 var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters{{ "id", 1 }};
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.xRegion, new Uri("xView", UriKind.Relative), navigationParameters);
```

from the xViewModel in constructor i try to get the navigationParameters id by

```
public xViewModel(NavigationParameters navigationParameters)
{
   var id = (int)navigationParameters["id"];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the navigation parameters in the constructor. You have to implement the `INavigationAware` interface in your view model.

```
public interface INavigationAware
{
    bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext);
}
```

The `OnNavigatedTo` method is called by Prism's navigation service automatically. It contains a `Parameters` property to access the navigation parameters, so you can do this:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
   var id = navigationContext.Parameters.GetValue<int>("id");
   // ...other code.
}
```

You can use the `GetValue<T>` and `GetValues<T>` methods on `NavigationParameters`, so you do not have to cast them yourself.

You can read more about view model participation in navigation in the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Navigation.html#view-and-view-model-participation-in-navigation).